# Why are there so many websites for the Korean K-ETA?

Tags: visas, online-resources, south-korea, k-eta

Why are there are so many websites for the Korean K-ETA?

This makes me think that it's a kind of scam or something non-related to the government. Does someone know why it works like this or can point to the real one from the list?

- `https://www.k-eta.go.kr`
- `https://www.k-eta.co/`
- `https://www.ketasouthkorea.com/`
- `https://www.koreaeta.kr/apply`

There are more of them, but this list is enough to show what makes me confused. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: .go.kr is the official page AFAIK. There are literally 000s of websites offering visa services for any country you like, typically charging an ‘admin’ fee for using them. A good way to find the legit site is to check official travel advice for your destination published by your home country government.

Comment: @Traveller thanks for the answer

Comment: Probably Google doesn't know about it. Many years ago there were a lot of scam for US ESTA. And so a lot of pressure to Google, and they banned adv of ESTA and I think also try to push back on search result scam sites. And they did for few other countries. Possibly K-ETA was not a thing at a time, and nobody at Google updated the list

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There's only one real K-ETA website, from the government: https://www.k-eta.go.kr/portal/apply/index.do

All others may or may not be legit, and even if they actually provide you with a K-ETA, they'll charge you for the privilege, on top of the government's fee.

**UPDATE:**

Citizens of 22 countries and regions are [exempted until end of 2024](https://www.k-eta.go.kr/portal/board/viewboarddetail.do?bbsSn=149899). Worth checking out to see if your country is in the list.

> Can you explain how you found the real from the government page and how to do this in general?

In the specific case of the K-ETA, it was easy: when I first learned about this, some airlines, including KAL, posted an announcement, with a link to the official website.

But in general, look for a `.go[v].TLD` website (here, .go.kr). Another common case is Vietnam: googling for `vietnam evisa` will give you a bunch of commercial websites, and one government website, with a very unfortunate domain name (because it's unmemorizable for most non-Vietnamese speakers), `evisa.xuatnhapcanh.gov.vn` (Vietnamese: *xuất nhập cảnh* 出入境 Immigration).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Can you explain how you found the real from the government page and how to do this in general?