# Is it possible to be rejected at South Korean border with approved k-eta?

Tags: borders, south-korea, denial-of-entry, k-eta

I'm from Kazakhstan, and we have the option to obtain a K-ETA for trips lasting less than 30 days. However, I've heard some stories about our citizens getting rejected at the border even if they have a K-ETA. I'm not sure if they really had a K-ETA. Can someone provide more information about the possibility of being rejected at the border with an approved K-ETA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a note about South Korea's K-ETA: it is not an option, it is mandatory if you are going to Korea without a visa (and can get visa-free access, as citizens of Kazakhstan can). In and of itself, the K-ETA doesn't give you anything but the right to fly to Korea. Your visa exemption is given to you on the basis of your passport.

The possibility of being denied entry in a foreign country is never zero. Which is why something like an ETA is a good tool to clear passengers ahead of travel. Between this and the checks airlines perform before letting you board, the chance of getting refused entry is much lower – but still non-zero.

Maybe the people you heard of had other issues, like passport validity (although the airlines would have caught that), or there was a dispute during inspection – from personal experience, 15 years living in Seoul, KIS officers can be extremely unpleasant for absolutely no reason. Or, they used [the wrong K-ETA website](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/184210/why-are-there-so-many-websites-for-the-korean-k-eta). And didn't have, in fact a K-ETA...

Just check you have everything in order, K-ETA, passport valid 6 months, onward/return ticket, etc. And you should be good.

Comment: OP has two options: the K-ETA, or a full visa.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. And this is true to any of "ETA" (and ESTA), but also with a visa.

ETA and visas are just "pre-checks". ETA just tell that there is probably no formal restriction to enter: valid passport (and country), no special case (e.g. crimes, bans), etc. Visas may have also extra documents (and checked by people who know the local documents and culture). Also ETA simplify data collecting: immigration officer need not to type (which can cause typos with foreign names and so problems).

But both of them are not an authorization to enter. Immigration officer should check if the intent are correct (for the type of visa). ETA is valid only for some cases. They may check also for other requirements: do you have funds, a return ticket (if required), vaccination (if required), health insurance (if required), etc. Or if there were significant changes since your ETA applications.

I would check the stories you got. I assume there were some reasons (some countries may be more strict on some interpretation of law).